# Why bother studying SARS-CoV-2 in mice? Why not start with rats?

Tags: zoology

[Mice, hamsters, ferrets, monkeys. Which lab animals can help defeat the new coronavirus? | Science | AAAS](https://www.sciencemag.org/news/2020/04/mice-hamsters-ferrets-monkeys-which-lab-animals-can-help-defeat-new-coronavirus)

> Other SARS-CoV-2 researchers are turning to rats. They are no more susceptible to COVID-19 than mice, but their larger size is an advantage. “You often want to do repetitive bleeding in an experiment, and you can’t do that with mice,” says Prem Premsrirut of Mirimus, whose company is collaborating with an academic group that’s using CRISPR to create a rat model with a human ACE2 receptor. Vaccine studies, for example, often assess how different doses affect antibody responses over several days. Premsrirut notes that “most toxicology studies” of drugs also start in rat. “If you can study a drug directly in rats, you’re a step ahead.”

I'm assuming that you can repetitively bleed rats, but not mice, because rats'  "larger size is an advantage", because

1. ["A rat weighing 400 g would therefore have a total blood volume (TBV) of approximately 64 ml/kg x 0.4 kg = 25.6 ml."](https://www.nc3rs.org.uk/rat-decision-tree-blood-sampling) But a [mouse weighing 25 g would therefore have a total blood volume (TBV) of approximately 58.5 ml/kg x 0.025 kg = 1.46 ml.](https://www.nc3rs.org.uk/mouse-decision-tree-blood-sampling)
2. the same percentage of TBV yields more blood in rats than mice.

[image]

Comment: Have you ever worked with either mice or rats?

Comment: Perhaps because (to borrow a phrase from NASA) mice are "smaller, faster, cheaper" than rats?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the knowledge base about mice is larger that that of rats.

Knockout mice were produced in 1989, knockout rats in 2003 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knockout_mouse)

The immunology of mice has been studied more than any other animal except humans. Correlations have been made between many components of immunology between mice and humans.